Excel - How to Increment Range
I am trying to increment a list of ranges of 19 from 5000 to 9999, like this:
RANGE
5000-5019
5020-5039
5040-5059
....
9980-9999

Is this easy for a non techie?

=5000+(ROW(A1)-1)*20&"-"&5000+(ROW(A1))*20-1 and drag down?

Try: =SEQUENCE(5000/20,,5000,20)&"-"&SEQUENCE(5000/20,,5019,20) or =LET(α, 5000, δ, 20, SEQUENCE(α/δ,,α,δ)&"-"&SEQUENCE(α/δ,,5019,δ))

Or this way: =LET(α, SEQUENCE(5000/20,,5000,20)+{0,19}, TAKE(α,,1)&"-"&TAKE(α,,-1))

Just for the sake of an answer posting it, BigBen Sir, has given the formula which would work for any versions, and alternatively adding the method for Modern Excel Versions:


Any Versions:
=5000+(ROW(A1)-1)*20&"-"&5000+(ROW(A1))*20-1


Modern Excel Versions:
=SEQUENCE(5000/20,,5000,20)&"-"&SEQUENCE(5000/20,,5019,20)


Or,
=LET(α, SEQUENCE(5000/20,,5000,20)+{0,19}, TAKE(α,,1)&"-"&TAKE(α,,-1))


